# How to find by Class in Python, with this example?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

This is the HTML:

```html
<div data-v-693e7786="" class="choices"><div data-v-693e7786="" class="choice"><span data-v-693e7786=""> 13 </span><!----></div><div data-v-693e7786="" class="choice"><span data-v-693e7786=""> 14 </span><!----></div><div data-v-693e7786="" class="choice"><span data-v-693e7786=""> 15 </span><!----></div></div>
```

from those three buttons:

[image]

I am trying to `driver.find_element_by_?` and I don't know how I can find it because those three buttons have neither an id nor a name.

For example, if I want the code to read the button with "14", what would the code look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to select any one of the button you can just use for instance this is the example for the button with **13**

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,' 13 ')]"));`